# Can I use part of my answer in a blog post for the Windows 8 contest?

Tags: support, superuser-blog, windows-8-challenge

I have an answer I'm working on but haven't posted it yet. I'm thinking I might end up using it (the whole thing) for *part* of my blog entry for the Windows 8 contest.

Is this allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, there's no reason why why can't use the answer to supplement your post.